# Karaf Commands to List Bundles

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

What is the difference in Karaf between the commands *list* and *la*?

My understanding is that both represent the command *bundle:list* ("Lists all installed bundles"). That's based on the results I see when I issue either the command *list --help* or *la --help*. In both cases, the help info provided in the console describes the *bundle:list* command.

However, these 2 commands (*list* and *la*) in fact do not yield the same results: when I issue the *list* command I'm shown a list of several bundles (14 actually in my current Karaf instance), all of which are in the **Active** state; but when I issue the *la* command I get a far longer list (137), most of which are in the **Active** state, but some of which show as **Resolved**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bundle:list gives you all bundles with a start level higher or equal to 50, while la is an alias to bundle:list -t 0 (list all). 
This is done because a lot of Karaf internal bundles are having a start level lower than 50, while all bundles being installed via bundle:deploy or by placing in the deploy folder automatically have start level 80.

Also, bundles being installed by means of features are usually deployed with start level 80, unless defined otherwise.

The difference between the **Active** and **Resolved** states is because Bundles can be **Active** while fragments can only be **Resolved**.

*edit*

Just issuing the bundle:list command will give you the following output:

```
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State | Lvl | Version | Name
---------------------------------
```

As can be seen, the Threshold is 50 and given.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Do you have a link to documentation of this?

Comment: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_unix_like_environment in the subsection of Aliases

Comment: Actually, bundle:list returns for me some bundles that have a start level of 50. This answer has still been helpful for me - but I question now the accuracy of the first part.

Comment: sorry, after looking at the sources, I corrected it to 50. Used to be 80 long time ago